# How to do I determine the context of an action in the view (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, viewmodel

I have a View that contains lots of links, when a user actions one of these links it initiates a filter action on the Controller.

When the View is constructing itself I want to determine which (if any) of the links have been actioned.

I'm overwhelmed with choices, put something in the ViewBag, TempData, or in my ViewModel so that the View can determine the context of the action?

What would be the preferred way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the preferred way?

**ViewModel** of course.

ViewBag achieves the same thing as the view model but in a weakly typed manner, so personally I never use it in any of my applications. `TempData` on the other hand could be considered as a one-redirect-session-storage which I don't see how it would be of any help for your scenario.